# To send two arguments to a function with the click of a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-signals

I have used QT Designer to have two QLineEdit's to take input from the user. After the user enters the values , when the Enter button is clicked I need the buttons to pass the values to the disk_angles function.

How to pass two strings to a function via signals with the press of a button?
Here is my code

```
class Maindialog(QMainWindow,diskgui.Ui_MainWindow):

    pass_arguments = SIGNAL((str,),(str,))

    def __init__(self,parent = None):

        super(Maindialog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.connect(self.Home,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.home_commands)
        self.connect(self.AutoFocus,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.auto_focus)

        self.Enter.clicked.connect(self.entervalues)
        self.connect(self,SIGNAL("pass arguments"),self.Criterion_disk_angles)

    def entervalues(self):
        if self.RotationEdit.text() != "" and self.TiltEdit.text() != "":
        self.RotationEdit = str(self.RotationEdit.text())
        self.TiltEdit = str(self.TiltEdit.text())
        self.pass_arguments.emit(self.RotationEdit,self.TiltEdit)

    def disk_angles(self,rotation_angle, tilt_angle):
```

I have tried to pass tuples as input to the signal 
        `pass_arguments = SIGNAL((str,),(str,))`
but I get the error

```
         pass_arguments = SIGNAL((str,),(str,))
         TypeError: SIGNAL() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Did you read the error? `SIGNAL` take 1 argument, but you provided 2...

Comment: @Andrew Li Yes but I read you can pass two arguments in a signal if you pass it as a tuple. But I mite have understood it wrong

Comment: try with pass_arguments = SIGNAL((str, str))

Comment: and self.pass_arguments.emit((self.RotationEdit,self.TiltEdit))

Comment: @RaghavendraMG `(str,),(str,)` isn't just one tuple, it's *two* tuples...

Comment: @ Andrew Li Thanks for the correction

Comment: @eyllanesc Now I am getting the error TypeError: 'SIGNAL' called with wrong argument types:
  SIGNAL(type, type)
Supported signatures:
  SIGNAL(unicode)

Comment: @RaghavendraMG Pass the correct type of argument... if you want tuples for multiple arguments learn about unpacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyQt5 it is recommended to use the [new style](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), In addition you are sending 2 tuples of place of one, here I show an example of a correct implementation.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton


class Widget(QObject):
    sig = pyqtSignal((str, str))

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.sig.connect(self.printer)

    def click(self):
        self.sig.emit("hello", "bye")

    def printer(self, text1, text2):
        print(text1, text2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QPushButton()
    w1 = Widget()
    w.clicked.connect(w1.click)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```